# Unable to execute aggregrate function and get result using Spring Data JPA

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am trying to perform aggregate operation for a particular date. Please find below query for same.

```java
@Modifying
@Query("SELECT new AggregateJourneyFoodOrder(mealRetrievalTime, SUM(head_count), SUM(bread), SUM(achar), SUM(jam) ,SUM(others), SUM(puri), SUM(roti), SUM(thepla))"
        + "  FROM JourneyFoodOrder WHERE isRemoved=false AND mealRetrievalTime = :mealRetrievalDate")
List<AggregateJourneyFoodOrder> getOrdersByDateAndNotDisabled(Boolean isRemoved, Date mealRetrievalDate);
```

I am getting below exceptions

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'journeyFoodServiceImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'journeyFoodServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\TiaaUser\Desktop\AWS\journeyfood\target\classes\org\brahmakumaris\journeyfood\service\JourneyFoodServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'journeyFoodOrderRepository' defined in org.brahmakumaris.journeyfood.repository.JourneyFoodOrderRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List org.brahmakumaris.journeyfood.repository.JourneyFoodOrderRepository.getOrdersByDateAndNotDisabled(java.lang.Boolean,java.util.Date) but parameter 'Optional[isRemoved]' not found in annotated query 'SELECT new AggregateJourneyFoodOrder(SUM(head_count), SUM(bread), SUM(achar), SUM(jam) ,SUM(others), SUM(puri), SUM(roti), SUM(thepla))  FROM JourneyFoodOrder WHERE isRemoved=false AND mealRetrievalTime = :mealRetrievalDate'!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'journeyFoodServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\TiaaUser\Desktop\AWS\journeyfood\target\classes\org\brahmakumaris\journeyfood\service\JourneyFoodServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'journeyFoodOrderRepository' defined in org.brahmakumaris.journeyfood.repository.JourneyFoodOrderRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List org.brahmakumaris.journeyfood.repository.JourneyFoodOrderRepository.getOrdersByDateAndNotDisabled(java.lang.Boolean,java.util.Date) but parameter 'Optional[isRemoved]' not found in annotated query 'SELECT new AggregateJourneyFoodOrder(SUM(head_count), SUM(bread), SUM(achar), SUM(jam) ,SUM(others), SUM(puri), SUM(roti), SUM(thepla))  FROM JourneyFoodOrder WHERE isRemoved=false AND mealRetrievalTime = :mealRetrievalDate'!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'journeyFoodOrderRepository' defined in org.brahmakumaris.journeyfood.repository.JourneyFoodOrderRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List org.brahmakumaris.journeyfood.repository.JourneyFoodOrderRepository.getOrdersByDateAndNotDisabled(java.lang.Boolean,java.util.Date) but parameter 'Optional[isRemoved]' not found in annotated query 'SELECT new AggregateJourneyFoodOrder(SUM(head_count), SUM(bread), SUM(achar), SUM(jam) ,SUM(others), SUM(puri), SUM(roti), SUM(thepla))  FROM JourneyFoodOrder WHERE isRemoved=false AND mealRetrievalTime = :mealRetrievalDate'!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List org.brahmakumaris.journeyfood.repository.JourneyFoodOrderRepository.getOrdersByDateAndNotDisabled(java.lang.Boolean,java.util.Date) but parameter 'Optional[isRemoved]' not found in annotated query 'SELECT new AggregateJourneyFoodOrder(SUM(head_count), SUM(bread), SUM(achar), SUM(jam) ,SUM(others), SUM(puri), SUM(roti), SUM(thepla))  FROM JourneyFoodOrder WHERE isRemoved=false AND mealRetrievalTime = :mealRetrievalDate'!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryMethod.assertParameterNamesInAnnotatedQuery(JpaQueryMethod.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryMethod.<init>(JpaQueryMethod.java:139)
```

**AggregateJourneyFoodOrder.java**

```java
public class AggregateJourneyFoodOrder {
    private int totalHeadCount;
    private int totalBread;
    private int totalAchar;
    private int totalJam;
    private int totalOthers;
    private int totalPuri;
    private int totalRoti;
    private int totalThepla;
    private Date mealRetrievalDate;
    //Getter Setters and Constructors
}
```

**JourneyFoodOrder.java**

```java
@Entity
public class JourneyFoodOrder{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long orderId;
        
    private Integer headCount;
        
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date dateOfOrderPlaced;
        
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date dateOfDeparture;
        
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a")
    private Date mealRetrievalTime;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private UserEntity user; 
        
    private Integer thepla;
        
    private Integer puri;
        
    private Integer roti;
    
    private Integer achar;
        
    private Integer jam;
        
    private Integer bread;
        
    private Integer others;
        
    private Boolean isRemoved;
    //Getters and setters
}
```

I am not getting what exactly I am doing wrong.  Also suggest if how query to perform aggregation operation for a particular date.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with aggregates functions, but with your attempt to apply the `LIKE` operator (and the wildcard modifier `%`) to an argument of type `Date` which does not work.

Since I'm not sure what that construct is even supposed to mean I can't really recommend an alternative beyond: Use either a `String` or a different comparison operator like `=` or `>=`.

*Note: The `@Modifying` annotation seems to be wrong since this query is a pure select query and should be executed as such.*

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to be working" mean exactly?

Comment: I changed query to - ` @Modifying @Query("SELECT new AggregateJourneyFoodOrder(SUM(head_count), SUM(bread), SUM(achar), SUM(jam) ,SUM(others), SUM(puri), SUM(roti), SUM(thepla))" + " FROM JourneyFoodOrder WHERE isRemoved=false AND mealRetrievalTime = :mealRetrievalDate") List<AggregateJourneyFoodOrder> getOrdersByDateAndNotDisabled(@Param("mealRetrievalDate")Date mealRetrievalDate);` but it don't change the error i am getting.

Comment: @Andronicus please let me know what exactly I am doing wrong here. I am new to Spring Data JPA and struggling to get result out of it.